# Adding push notification to already existing app - cant get it to work

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I already have an app in the appstore.  Now I wanted to add APNS.  On the developer portal I setup a developer certificate and enabled my app for APNS.  I created a new provisioning
profile and set that in my app under Debug.  Ive removed all other provisioning profiles.

When I run my app on my iphone, I send registerForRemoteNotificationTypes but never
get a response from apple, nor is the error delegate ever called.  If I remove the app
on the iphone and re-install, it never asks about push notifications.

Ive read through as many stack overflow articles and tutorials/Apple docs on the subject in the last 2 days as I can find and nothing seems to fix my issue thus far.

Other things Ive checked:
- Checked the Entitlements.plist file for bad keys
- Checked the downloaded .mobileprovision file for aps-environment with development string
- Removed every other provision profile in my Organizer -> Device as well as the Keychain
- Changed the date on my iphone to a day forward, powered off, powered on, reloaded app

Does anyone have any other suggestions on what to try or an answer as to why trying to
setup APNS on an existing app doesnt seem to work?

Note that Im trying to develop a new version with APNS, not asking why the released
version doesnt work yet.  Once I can debug with APNS, then Ill go for the disto APNS.
Thanks in advance.

[EDIT]  I think you misunderstood my question.  Ive already read through the docs and
gone through the steps.  In fact, this same code worked at one time and I disabled it
temporarily a couple major revs ago, but now want to re-enable it.  Ive also seen that
same Tutorial.  The main problem as far as I can tell is NOT my code, its the provision
profile or something to do with a bug with Apple and how its handling the push certificate
in an existing file or something.

Here's my code, but as I said, I dont think its my code at this point, its something with
the provisioning or something.  Ive verified I call this, but never get a callback to
one of the delegates after getting the push certificate setup on the IOS Dev site as well
as getting a new provisioning profile WITH push in it.

```
[application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationType)
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
      UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
      UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) ];
```

Delegates never get called:

```
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    [Log log:TINFO :@"==== APNS didRegisterForRemoteNotifcationsWithDeviceToken ===="];

    NSString *devtok = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",deviceToken];
    devtok = [devtok stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"" withString: @""];
    devtok = [devtok stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];

    NSString *stok = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", devtok] autorelease];

    [Log log:TINFO :@"saving ", devtok];

    UpdateDevToken *utok = [[UpdateDevToken alloc] autorelease];
    [utok updateDeviceToken:stok];

}
```

Error Delegate:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application    didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [Log log:TERR :@"==== APNS didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@", error.localizedDescription];
}
```

[Edit 2]  Forgot to add that I also have didReceiveRemoteNotification:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
[Log log:TENT :@"==== APNS didReceiveRemoteNotification"];
}
```

None of my delegates ever get called.

Comment: please show your registering and delegate code, and that may help figure out where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

To start with [See Apple doc on APNS.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html)

Check out the [Raywander Tutorial.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

Then modify our AppDelegate Class.

```
      // Add This to did to 
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        ........
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
       return YES;
    }

    - (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
        {
            NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

            if ([defaults valueForKey:@"device_token"]) { // Check existing device token
                NSLog(@"My saved token is: %@", [defaults valueForKey:@"device_token"]);
            }

            NSString *deviceTokenString = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
            deviceTokenString = [deviceTokenString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

            [defaults setObject:deviceTokenString forKey:@"device_token"];
            [defaults synchronize];

            NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceTokenString);
        }

        - (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
        {
            NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error);
            //[self showAlertMessage:@"Failed to get token, error!"];

        }
        - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
        {
            NSLog(@"userInfo :%@",userInfo);
            //[self setUser:[[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"]];
        }
```